How to detect and trigger my code when initial data is fetched from useQuery()
In my React app I have a fully controlled <select>, the values of which are retrieved from the server using TanStack react-query. What I want to do is automatically select the first item only when the data is initially retrieved from the server, but not if it gets re-fetched in the background while the user is editing the form.
What I have at the moment is this:
const [selectedWidget, setSelectedWidget] = useState<string | null>(null)

const myQuery = useQuery({...})

useEffect(() => {
    if (!selectedWidget) {
        setSelectedWidget(myQuery.data?.[0]?.id ?? null)
    }
}, [myQuery.data, selectedWidget])

<select 
    value={selectedWidget ?? ""}
    onChange={e => setSelectedWidget(e.target.value)}>
    {
        myQuery.data.map(x =>
            <option key={x.id} value={x.id}>{x.description}</option>
        )
    }
</select>

It seems to work OK but the point of react-query is to stop me being reliant on useEffect(), so is there a better way to do this without it?

possible duplicate of https://stackoverflow.com/questions/77667983

ParentComponent.tsx
const {data: queryData, isLoading: isLoadingQueryData} = useQuery({...})
{ !isLoadingQueryData && <SelectComponent queryData={queryData}/> }

SelectComponent.tsx
const [selectedWidget, setSelectedWidget] = useState(queryData?.[0]?.id || null)
<select 
    value={selectedWidget ?? ""}
    onChange={e => setSelectedWidget(e.target.value)}>
    {
        myQuery.data.map(x =>
            <option key={x.id} value={x.id}>{x.description}</option>
        )
    }
</select>


Thanks - this is basically the same as the accepted answer to a similar question https://stackoverflow.com/questions/77667983

You can leverage local state with fallback as well:
function Component() {
  const [state, setState] = useState()

  const { data } = useQuery(...)

  const value = state ?? data?.[0]?.id ?? null

  return <select value={value} onChange={e => setState(e.target.value)}>...</select>
}

On initial render, the value would be undefined. As soon as the query loads, it will use the first ID in the data set. However, if the user changes the value, then state can no longer be undefined, so it will keep the user selected value even if the query refetches and the first ID changes.

Hmm, this is a neat and compact solution but it doesn't seem very clean because the state variable doesn't always reflect the value that is selected in the dropdown.

Also this doesn't work if the user was allowed to select blank (which my scenario doesn't allow but is a perfectly reasonable thing in general)

It's a solution that the library maintainer describes in his blog here https://tkdodo.eu/blog/react-query-and-forms#keeping-background-updates-on, and I disagree that it's not clean enough, the state simply represents something else that the value on select, it represents the "user choice" so you can call it const [userChoice, setUserChoice] = useState() with const selectedValue = userChoice ?? initialValue and it becomes very clear and clean, in my opinion. For the other one, if user can choose undefined, it stops working, I'd have either "" or null as "empty choice" for the user.
